# Win+Space not working in RDP from Mac to Windows

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, remote-desktop

I'm using Microsoft Remote Desktop app to logon to a Windows machine from macOS (Mojave). It looks like most keys are mapped automatically. For example I'm able to do Ctrl-C and Ctrl-V without any issue in Windows. However, one particular shortcut I cannot get to work is **Window Key+Space**, which is used to switch input method in Windows. It looks like whenever I press these two keys it is macOS who gets it. In Windows RDP two separate keys are received, so the start menu would pop up (Window Key), and a space would be entered (space key). Has anyone seen this issue and is there a solution?

I'm using Karabiner-Elements for some shortcuts in Mac. I tried disabling it, but still got the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

macOS will always 'steal' any key command that is global to the Mac & not pass it on to any remote connection. Cmd/space is the global command for Spotlight (though it can also be used for 'switch input source'). The Win key on a PC keyboard is interpreted as Cmd on a Mac.

Check on the Mac, System Prefs > Keyboard > Keyboard >
In two of the sections in the left column, Spotlight and Input Sources, see if either is set to use Cmd/Space.
If so, disable, or change to another key combo.

btw, some specific key combos on Microsoft RDC for Mac will automatically remap. Cmd/C, V, X, for instance, will automatically remap to Ctrl/C, V, X. Most other global shortcuts do not remap.